# How do i get the guild ID of a joined user/member (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {

settingss.findOne({
  guildID: guild.ID // <---- Trying to figure out what i want over here
}, async (err, settings) => {

    var role = member.guild.roles.cache.get(role => role.name === settingss.joinrolename);

    if (!role) return;

    member.roles.add(role);

    const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(channel => channel.name === settingss.welcomechannelname);

    if (!channel) return;

    channel.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member}`);

  });

});
```

i cant seem to figuere out how to get guild ID over here.

I tried guild.memberCount this didnt work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that `member.guild.id` should do the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `member` parameter to get the guild ID using `member.guild.id`:

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {

  settingss.findOne({
    guildID: member.guild.id
  }, async (err, settings) => {

    var role = member.guild.roles.cache.get(role => role.name === settingss.joinrolename);

    if (!role) return;

    member.roles.add(role);

    const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(channel => channel.name === settingss.welcomechannelname);

    if (!channel) return;

    channel.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member}`);

  });

});
```